# Laravel Eloquent getting data from relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have `Task` model. My `Task` model has some relationships and it currently looks like this:

```
class Task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(City::class, 'id', 'city_id');
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Type::class, 'id', 'type_id');
    }

    public function note()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Note::class, 'id', 'note_id');
    }

    public function operator()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'operator_id');
    }
}
```

Now, in my `TasksController` I need to get Tasks that match certain criteria, like this:

```
$tasks = Task::whereCityId($city->id)->whereTypeId($type->id)->get()->toArray();
```

The problem is that fields named `city_id` `type_id` `note_id` `operator_id` will get my `integer` values that they have.

Instead I would like to get certain value from a related Model.

For example:

> `operator_id` should be replaced with `username` from User table that corresponds to the user id.

An obvious solution to this would be to simply use `foreach` loop, go through my results and get the data I need and simply create another array with the information replaced, but I am not sure if this is the best idea and perhaps there is something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change in your code:

```
$this->hasOne(ClassName::class, 'id', 'foreign_key');
```

To

```
$this->belongsTo(ClassName::class, 'foreign_key', 'id');
```

because Task's id does not available as foreign key in these tables. These table's id present in task table as foreign key so you have to use **belongsTo()** relationship to tell script from where these id belongs.

Then access properties like this:

```
$tasks = Task::with("type", "city", "operator")
->whereCityId($city->id)->whereTypeId($type->id)->get();

foreach($tasks as $task){
   echo $task->city->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help better than what you ask.

```
$tasks = Task::whereCityId($city->id)
->whereTypeId($type->id)
->with('operator')
->get()->toArray();
```

`with('operator')` is ORM feature that make you collection to include its relation as collection property. In this case it will convert to array property.

you could access it from your `foreach` function as

```
@foreach($task as $key)
$key['operator']['username']
@endforeach
```

Have a nice day

Comment: it would be better if you check before calling it on your foreach loop.

Comment: `isset($key['operator']) ? $key['operator']['username'] : ''`

Answer (score 0):

first you should fix your relation:

```
public function city()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(City::class,'city_id','id'); 
    }
```

and so one the same error, foreign key in argument order comes before the primary key.

after that you can use [addSelect](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#subquery-selects):

```
 $tasks = Task::whereCityId($city->id)->whereTypeId($type->id)
            ->addSelect(['userName' => User::select('name')
                ->whereColumn('users.id', 'tasks.operator_id')
                ->limit(1)])->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: as you said, foreign key comes before the primary key. My Task contains field of `city_id` which related to City where each city is stored as constant and has its own primary key. Therefore my relation is correct in this scenario

Comment: no it 's not, see: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: When I change my relation to the one that you are suggesting, I am getting this error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cities.city_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `cities` where `cities`.`city_id` = 1 and `cities`.`city_id` is not null limit 1) `